# How to display data with variation to unsophisticated users?

Tags: info-visualisation, statistics

In my application, students are grouped into classes and each student has a performance metric. I want to be able to show teachers and principals a list of classes, along with an aggregate performance metric for each class.

I don't want to show the mean, because one very high or low performing student skews this. I don't want to show the median, because this basically discards the very high or low performing students entirely, and I want to capture the contribution of these students.

More correct would probably be to show a visualization of the mean with standard deviation. Conceivably I could show a little bell curve sparkline to convey this. But even then, I think this would be too sophisticated for many of my users, and it's not a single number that could be used, for instance, to sort the list by "performance".

Is there a better technique for computing aggregate performance into a single number that somehow captures the variance of the data set?

Comment: Although information visualisation and displaying statistics is in the scope of this site, you might get better advice on calculating the single value needed at [stats.se]

Comment: Agreed, but even if there isn't a better statistical technique, I need a good way to represent the statistics I've got.

Comment: Hi Josh. I feel that the "single number" and the "captures the variance" goals are at odds with each other. Your instincts to use a bell curve sound spot on to me. Simply add a single line callout with your aggregate number and let the curve communicate the variance.

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider giving **median** with a **label**

- **very uneven** (red) : std > 4
- **uneven** (orange) : std > 2
- **homogeneous** (green) : std <= 2

Sometimes if you draw the statistical distribution, it shows two maxima, showing that there are **two groups** of students. This might also be an interesting indicator.

When I was in prep' school in France one teacher was very alarmed because the average was increasing but the students were splitting into two categories (high-level increasing, low-level decreasing) showing two very different student types (maybe discouraged or boosted by pressure).

According to me, you should show this curves but after a click, or on user demand if it is a website. As your user become more and more expert with your tool you can start introducing your statistics at first sight.

**Example**

[image: Examples of chips showing notes and label]

I put a color on each label, but you should define with your users what event is to be red or green. I put my personal point of view on the colors (I personnaly think that classes of level are better).

Comment: This is an interesting idea. Do you have any example images showing this kind of visualization?

Comment: Added sketch to the main message :)